# How to implement new key events to open the drop-down for `select` element in FF instead of default Alt+down

Tags: jquery, html, browser, accessibility

I am creating accessibility website, where the user can use keyboard to access the controls on the website.

The `select` element of HTML can be accessed using enter/Space keys to pull down the drop-down menu in Chrome, but the same is differently accessible in FF. We want to use Alt+up/ Alt+down to close and open the drop-down respectively.

I want to change this behavior in FF and want to keep it consistent across the browser. Therefore I want to make the control access with Enter/Space keys as in Chrome.

```
$('select').bind('keypress',function(event){
    if('MozBoxSizing' in document.body.style){
        if(event.which == 13 || event.which == 32){
            console.log("key pressed:" + event.which);
            $(this).trigger(click);
        }
    }
});
```

This is throwing an error:

```
"key pressed:13" Util.js:38
ReferenceError: click is not defined Util.js:39
"key pressed:32" Util.js:38
ReferenceError: click is not defined
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Wrap the event name in quotes `$(this).trigger(click);` ==> `$(this).trigger('click');`

Comment: :( Still not working. But no error this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible to change default behavior of SELECT in fireFox

you can try Jquery UI ComboBox

which provide you full control over behavior and you change according to your need.

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

or you can try Select2

https://select2.github.io/

if you need some help in customization you can comment here i will explain how to customize these 2 controls

Comment: Will this work for Keyboard events? I see that auto complete combo-box cannot be accessed using Enter/Space in Chrome

Comment: May I know how to display options vertically and increase the height of the drop-down in ***Select2**?

Comment: find .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single style in select2.min.css and add height style

Comment: are you using select2 or combobox ui